# How can I put my windows Users Program Files, and Windows Directories on the same partition?

Tags: windows-7, windows, service-pack

Im trying to upgrade my Windows 7 to Windows 7 SP1, however I constantly get error [80070490](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-update-error-80070490#1TC=windows-7). Going through the guides I ran sfc, repaired a corrupted file, but still got the error. I then ran the system update readiness tool but still no luck. So I moved to the next part: repairing windows. However, when I follow the steps to repair windows and on the upgrade step I get this error:

[image]

It seems windows is complaining that my user, Program Files, and Windows Directories are not in the same partition.

I'm presuming this is happening because I have an HDD (C drive) and an SSD (E drive). The SSD is where Windows is installed, but both C and E have a users and Program Files folder. How can I set them all in the same partition?

Comment: Are you trying to upgrade it on C? If yes , there must be Windows installed on it also.

Comment: @Scorpion99 I never specify where it is going to be upgraded, but presumably it would choose E, where WIndows is currently installed

Comment: How can u make sure that's it is E? Disconnect E and then try to upgrade and see the results.

Comment: @Scorpion99 Well E has my installation of windows, so its going to be kinda hard to boot up without that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it says, "Moving these is also not supported" it is referring to the fact that doing so rarely results in a reliable system, upgrade or no. The problem here is that many programs make absolute references to files inside these folders, so if you move the folder then the file is not found.

If you type **set** in a cmd (dos) prompt and press enter, it will give you a list of environment variables, some of which tell you where Windows thinks these folders actually are.

If they *are* actually on separate drives, that is not an easy thing to alter without breaking things because of the absolute references. Change the location and you have to fix-up numerous settings. In fact, probably less work to do a clean install in that case.

Comment: Yeah, looks like some program files is on C, some is on E, windows is on E, program data is on C... bit of a mess.